# Sum variables in a dataframe and plot the sum in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have dataframe that contains data on the number of TVs and radios owned by survey respondents now and before:

```
DF <- data.frame(TV_now = as.numeric(c(4, 9, 1, 0, 4, NA)),
                 TV_before = as.numeric(c(4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2)),
                 Radio_now = as.numeric(c(4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 9)),
                 Radio_before = as.numeric(c(6, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10)))
```

I want to sum the total value of each variable and then create a barplot that shows the number of TVs and radios owned by survey respondents now and before.

I can manually create a new dataframe that contains just the sum of the value of each variable in the original DF

```
DFsum <- data.frame(TV_now = as.numeric(c(sum(DF$TV_now,na.rm = TRUE))),
                    TV_before = as.numeric(c(sum(DF$TV_before,na.rm = TRUE))),
                    Radio_now = as.numeric(c(sum(DF$TV_now,na.rm = TRUE))),
                    Radio_before = as.numeric(c(sum(DF$Radio_before,na.rm = TRUE))))
```

and then use `tidyr` to do the following:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
DFsum %>% 
  gather(key=Device, value=Number) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Number,fill=Device)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Device, y = Number), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

This gives me the result I want, but seems unnecessarily complicated for what should be easy to achieve. Is there an easier way to plot this?

Comment: Vectors like `c(4, 9, 1, 0, 4, NA)` are numeric, you don't have to use `as.numeric` on them. You also might be interested in the `colSums` function.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you sum, as ggplot will stack the similarly-filled bars anyway: `DF %>% 
    gather(Device, Number) %>% 
    drop_na(Number) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Device, Number, fill = Device)) + 
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code with use of `dplyr::mutate_all` since you are summarizing all your columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% mutate_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  gather(key=Device, value=Number) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Device,fill=Device)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Device, y = Number), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Excellent. This is very helpful. Do you know why your code results in "Number" on both x and y axes? It's easy to correct with `xlab("Device type")`, but a mild annoyance nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify data creation. R knows that 4, 9, 1, etc., are numbers, you don't need `as.numeric`.

```
DF <- data.frame(TV_now = c(4, 9, 1, 0, 4, NA),
                 TV_before = c(4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2),
                 Radio_now = c(4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 9),
                 Radio_before = c(6, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10))
```

Simplify the data manipulation. Tidy your data (convert it to long format) first, then do other things:

```
DF_long = gather(DF, key = "device") %>%
    group_by(device) %>%
    summarize(number = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Simplify the plotting. Aesthetics are inherited - you don't need to specify them multiple times. `geom_col` is preferred to `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"`. `position = "dodge"` does nothing when there is one group per x index.

```
ggplot(aes(x = device, y = number, fill = device)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

---

I generally prefer to do my own data manipulation, but we can also lean on `ggplot`s stacking bars to replace the summing, making the entire code:

```
gather(DF, key = "device", value = "number") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = device, y = number, fill = device)) +
    geom_col()
```

---

Base approach

```
dev = colSums(DF, na.rm = TRUE)
barplot(dev, col = factor(names(dev)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's very good point. We should work on data in long format.